# Cancel repeating thread in python if it takes longer than 15 seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have a function that calls itself again after completion with a delay. They goal is that the function `doSomething` runs roughly every 5 seconds. However if the function needs more than 15 seconds the thread should be cancelled.
How can I add the condition that the thread gets killed if it takes to long? If it takes more than 15 seconds I want it to cancel and try again.

Here is the code that I have but I was not able to add a canceling condition yet.

```
def repeatProcess(self):
  # do no tracking if it was set to offline
  start = time.time()
  doSomething()
  print(f"Execution time {time.time() - start}")
  delayTimer = threading.Timer(timerSeconds, self.repeatProcess)
  delayTimer.start()

def doSomething(self):
  print("do some stuff that may take time")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  trackingThread = threading.Thread(name='repeatThread', target=repeatProcess)
  trackingThread.daemon = True
  trackingThread.start()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+kill+thread. In summary, your approach is bound to fail. You might be able to use multiprocessing instead, but it's not clear due to lack of details.

Comment: I want a function to repeat every x seconds. If it takes to long I want it to abord an try again.

Comment: Yes, so much is clear, and it's not enough to make a good suggestion how to do it properly.

Comment: Well can you tell me what is missing? I am trying to read something with the function. This can take longer than 15 seconds. If it happens I want it to abort and try again later.